# How to debug a failing Ember Data JSON API save() operation?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm creating an Ember Data object with this action in a route:

```
    createProfile: function() {
        var profile = this.store.createRecord('profile', {
            username: 'bob',
            orientation: 'straight',
            gender: 'male',
            firstname: 'kevin',
            lastlogin: 'today'
        });
        profile.save().then(function() {
            this.transitionTo('welcome');
        });
    }
```

On the server side I've handling the POST request and returning a response that looks like this:

```
Request URL: http://0.0.0.0/api/1/profiles
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 201 Created  <-- It has got the "Green Dot" in Ember Inspector

Response headers:
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 164
Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 07 Oct 2015 07:17:06 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Location: http://localhost/api/1/profiles/2
Server: waitress
access-control-allow-credentials: true
```

And the body of the response looks like this:

```
{'data': {'type': 'profiles', 'attributes': {'firstname': 'kevin', 'lastlogin': 'today', 'username': 'bob', 'orientation': 'straight', 'gender': 'male'}, 'id': '2'}}
```

As far as I can tell, this all looks good. I've done another operation that successfully does a GET method on this model type. I can see the model appear in the Ember Inspector under the Ember Data panel and see it is correctly given an Id of 2.

But then when the server returns the response the error message is:

```
createProfile/<@http://localhost/assets/emberpd.js:324:6
tryCatch@http://localhost/assets/vendor.js:60951:14
invokeCallback@http://localhost/assets/vendor.js:60966:15
publish@http://localhost/assets/vendor.js:60934:9
@http://localhost/assets/vendor.js:40181:7
Queue.prototype.invoke@http://localhost/assets/vendor.js:11532:9
Queue.prototype.flush@http://localhost/assets/vendor.js:11596:11
DeferredActionQueues.prototype.flush@http://localhost/assets/vendor.js:11392:11
Backburner.prototype.end@http://localhost/assets/vendor.js:10720:9
Backburner.prototype.run@http://localhost/assets/vendor.js:10842:13
run@http://localhost/assets/vendor.js:29679:12
ember$data$lib$adapters$rest$adapter$$RESTAdapter<.ajax/</hash.success@http://localhost/assets/vendor.js:66323:15
jQuery.Callbacks/fire@http://localhost/assets/vendor.js:3350:10
jQuery.Callbacks/self.fireWith@http://localhost/assets/vendor.js:3462:7
done@http://localhost/assets/vendor.js:9516:5
.send/callback@http://localhost/assets/vendor.js:9920:8
```

At which point I feel pretty stuck. I'm using Ember 2.0.2 with Ember Data 2.0.1.

Any idea if there is something obvious I'm missing?

Am I doing something wrong in the .then() function? Or is this an Ember Data problem? Any idea where I start going in to debug that kind of error?

Comment: Is there an `errors` array? Can you sprinkle `Ember.Logger.log(error)` into the `error()` hook of your route or the application route? What if you just `POST` that JSON directly to the server? (I assume that works fine?)

Comment: Is the error message complete? it usually has a header describing the problem...

Comment: `profile.save().then(() => this.transitionTo('welcome')).catch(console.log.bind(console));` Do you get anything in the console?

Comment: I think your problem here is `this.transitionTo('welcome');` since you don't pass `this`

Answer (score 1):

The `this` in your promise has a different scope from the `this` you are expecting. You can rewrite it as follows (where you set `_this` to `this` before handling the promise):

```
createProfile: function() {
  var profile = this.store.createRecord('profile', {
    username: 'bob',
    orientation: 'straight',
    gender: 'male',
    firstname: 'kevin',
    lastlogin: 'today'
  });

  var _this = this;
  profile.save().then(function() {
    _this.transitionTo('welcome');
  });
}
```

In ES6, you can rewrite this to avoid having to set `_this` at all:

```
createProfile() {
  const profile = this.store.createRecord('profile', {
    username: 'bob',
    orientation: 'straight',
    gender: 'male',
    firstname: 'kevin',
    lastlogin: 'today'
  });

  profile.save().then(() => {
    this.transitionTo('welcome');
  });
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this fixes the problem. Now I'm back on track (and need to read more about scope and promises).Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would propose that it fails to parse the payload from response to POST request. Does it have the same structure as the one for GET request?

Anyway, if I were you I would set a breakpoint in [handleResponse](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_handleResponse) method and walk through parsing the payload to figure out what is wrong.